# IabHelper service not working

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Im using inApp billing service , when I published my project everything was Ok in all devices but there is a problem is some huawei models like p9 lite !!

After debugging , I figured out the problem is in this line:

```
mHelper.startSetup(setupListener);
```

so I checked the `startSetup` method codes and finally understood `context.bindService` always returns `False` value , so billing service cant start in these phones :(

**`context.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`**

Permisions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.farsitel.bazaar.permission.PAY_THROUGH_BAZAAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Starting IabHelper :

```
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this,getBazarKey());
    mHelper.setContext(this);
    inv_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (checkInstalled()) {
        try {
            mHelper.startSetup(setupListener);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "bazaar is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct permission must be used is `com.android.vending.BILLING`